# JAVA recursive bisection for finding root

Tags: java, recursion

```
public double RecursiveRoot(Function f, double left, double right, double midPoint, double epsilon){

    midPoint=(right + left)/2;

if(midPoint>epsilon){
        if(f.f(right)*f.f(midPoint)<0){
            left=midPoint;
        }
        else{
            right=midPoint;
        }

    }
    return RecursiveRoot(f, left, right, midPoint, epsilon);
}
```

So having a recursive method for root finding it gives me stackoverflow error, which means  I probably don't stop the method from calling itself far too many times(infinite loop), even though having a return. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You are correct about the stack overflow.

Comment: Well, i don't see any point where you stop the function before `return RecursiveRoot(f, left, right, midPoint, epsilon);` When the function should be stopped?

Comment: Your recursion is missing a [base case.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_case)

Comment: Step 1: print some stuff to see what's happening. You might notice something. @MattBall is onto something

Comment: Your assumptions could be wrong.

Comment: So your method does some stuff, then it calls itself, after which it returns. So if every level creates a new stack level before it returns, when exactly is the return statement going to be executed?